# Small filtered colimit in category of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small filtered category and $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\textbf{Ab}$ be a functor. Let $U:\textbf{Ab}\rightarrow\textbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor. Then the filtered colimit
$$\left(\coprod_{C\in\mathcal{C}}U(F(C))/\sim,(s_C)_{C\in\mathcal{C}}\right)$$
of the functor $U\circ F$ exists. We want to construct an abelian group structure on the set $\coprod_{C\in\mathcal{C}}U(F(C))/\sim$.

Let $C,C'\in\mathcal{C}$ and $x\in F(C)$, $y\in F(C')$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is filtered, there exists an object $C''\in\mathcal{C}$ together with morphisms $f:C\rightarrow C''$ and $g:C'\rightarrow C''$ such that $s_{C''}(F(f)(x))=s_C(x)$ and $s_{C''}(F(g)(y))=s_{C'}(y)$. Let
$$s_C(x)+s_{C'}(y):=s_{C''}(F(f)(x)+F(g)(y)).$$

I want to show that this operation does not depend on the choices made. Is it enough to pick elements in $x'\in F(C)$ and $y'\in F(C')$ such that $s_C(x)=s_C(x')$ and $s_{C'}(y)=s_{C'}(y')$, or do I have to pick different $C$'s in $\mathcal{C}$ as well?

Supposing that merely picking $x'\in F(C)$ and $y'\in F(C')$ such that $s_C(x)=s_C(x')$ and $s_{C'}(y)=s_{C'}(y')$ suffices, let us show that $s_C(x)+s_{C'}(y)=s_{C}(x')+s_{C'}(y')$. Once again there exists an object $C'''\in\mathcal{C}$ and morphisms $f':C\rightarrow C'''$ and $g':C'\rightarrow C'''$ such that $s_{C'''}(F(f')(x'))=s_C(x')$ and $s_{C'''}(F(g')(y'))=s_{C'}(y')$. What should be the next step? Any hints?

Comment: Yes, you should prove that it does not depend on the choice of $C$ and $C'$.

Comment: Another (arguably nicer) way of building limits in algebraic categories that allow you to glue objects (essentially via quotients) is to take the direct sum of all of the individual pieces, and quotient out so that the equivalence relation holds. You can use isomorphism theorems to show that it actually is a colimit, and then the group structure is automatic.